# Search (Custom Form, Custom Search Result)

Tags: wp-query, search

If I have a form:

```
<form class="search" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/page-search?category=2" method="get">
    <input type="text" required name="search" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit" class="sprite-psuedo"></button>
</form>
```

How would I add the custom page-search,

The

```
<?php
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>
```

From Tutorial does not work. (Outputs nothing, it doesn't really seem to do anything). I tried too loop as well..

How do I process the form?

Comment: Which tutorial? Where did you put this code?

Comment: The code is put on page-search.php

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Answer (score -2):

Try fetching as `$_GET['category']`.

Then u can use it whichever way u like